a.id().required() for model.identifier() TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
I am trying to make a simple schema for a book. For some reason, the UUID generated by a.id() is a type 'string', cannot be the identifier? Do I need to create an autoincremented integer ID value, and if so, how do I specify this in the schema and to GraphQL? I'm familiar with SQL languages. Would be nice to use a GUID.
The code
import { type ClientSchema, a, defineData } from '@aws-amplify/backend';

const schema = a.schema({
  Book: a
    .model({
      bookId: a.id().required(),
      name: a.string(),
      publisher: a.url(),
      inLanguage: a.string(),
      ISBN: a.integer(),
      author: a.url(),
      image: a.url(),
      numberOfPages: a.integer(),
      datePublished: a.date()
    })
    .identifier(["bookId"])
    .authorization((allow) => [allow.guest()]),
});

The error
webpack 5.91.0 compiled with 1 error in 199 ms
assets by status 4.46 MiB [cached] 2 assets
cached modules 4.69 MiB (javascript) 27.8 KiB (runtime) [cached] 1532 modules
./amplify_outputs.json 2.24 KiB [built]
ERROR in D:\Code\project\amplify\data\resource.ts
23:17-25
[tsl] ERROR in D:\Code\AWS-Trico\amplify\data\resource.ts(23,18)
      TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
ts-loader-default_e3b0c44298fc1c14


Also, if I want the ability to allow access to the schema publicly, can I still restrict access to the form to create a book behind access control?
